# in python with ctypes change value of parameter in an object adress

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm trying to program a linked list for a school activity, but for the library `ctypes` if I want to change the parameter of a object that stores an address only having the address of the object in question how do I do it.

For example, if I want to add a node at the end and I have the address of the last node(which is an object) I need to change the value from None to the address of the new node created, how can I do this?

also it's my first time asking a question sorry if I'm not giving enough detail, if there is any more information important to answer tell me

This is what I tried but obviously didn't work because I'm just making `this_Node` equal to the object and then changing `this_Node` itself and not the actual value in the address but I don't really know how to do it

```py
    this_Node = ctypes.cast(this_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value
    this_Node.next = new_node_adress
```

the whole code

```py
import ctypes 

class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next 
#initialise linked list
LinkedList = []
for i in range(0,10):
    LinkedList.append(Node(i,None))
for i in range(0,9):
    LinkedList[i].next = id(LinkedList[i+1])
root_pointer= id(LinkedList[0])
#print(ctypes.cast(root_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value.data)

#search in linked list 
def search_value(root_pointer,f):
    found = False
    this_address = root_pointer
    this_Node = ctypes.cast(root_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value
    this_pointer = this_Node.next
    while this_Node.next != None and found == False:
        #print(this_Node.data)
        if f == this_Node.data:
            found = True
            print(f,"was found in address",this_address)
        else:
            this_address = this_Node.next
            this_Node = ctypes.cast(this_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value
            this_pointer = this_Node.next
    if found ==False:
        print(f,"was not in the list")
    return found, this_address,this_Node,this_pointer

def end_add(root_pointer,new_node_adress):
    this_address = root_pointer
    this_Node = ctypes.cast(root_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value
    this_pointer = this_Node.next
    while this_Node.next != None:
        this_address = this_Node.next
        this_Node = ctypes.cast(this_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value
        this_pointer = this_Node.next
    this_Node.next = new_node_adress
    

f = 34
a = Node(34,None)
end_add(root_pointer,id(a))
#print(ctypes.cast(root_pointer, ctypes.py_object).value.data)
found,this_address,this_Node,this_pointer=search_value(root_pointer,f)
```

also sorry if its not very well structured but Im newish with python

Comment: Unless you were specifically tasked to use `ctypes`, this is a really wrong way to do this. This is not the way to program in Python. You do not need `ctypes` for this task. Python does not use memory addresses or pointers unless you're specifically interacting with a compiled library that doesn't have Python bindings. Search "linked list python" on the internet instead.

Comment: I was not specifically tasked with using them, but my teacher was using it in their example, I was just tasked on making a linked list using the adresses of the objects, im not that experienced and my teacher didnt post the example so I dont really know how to do it. should I post all of the code? well anyways I guess I will do it a diferent way, but im still curious if there is a way of changing the value in the adress

Comment: Yea, feel free to post the entire code, and then to show us with a second smaller snippet exactly what you do not understand. Ofcourse each teaching context is different, but using `ctypes` seems highly irregular.

Comment: the teacher didnt really explain us how to do it she only explayned the theory of what a linked list was and she told us to try to do it and use adresses, actually now that I remember maybe in her example she didnt have that library, but when I searched on the internet how to use adresses I found that library and started using it, I only managed to get the search part working but not the node adding one

Comment: There is alot going on in the example code. Beginning with the nonsensical use of pointers: `root_pointer= id(LinkedList[0])` makes no sense, `id` does return the memory address of a Python object, but that's a CPython implementation detail, it won't work in all version of Python. All these attempts at pointers and memory addresses could be replaced by simple assignments, since mutable Python objects are by default "by reference". I think your teacher may come from a C/C++ background and has misunderstood some Python fundamentals, or is trying to teach something very specific and unpythonic.

Comment: This is a very good resource on linked lists: https://realpython.com/linked-lists-python/#implementing-your-own-linked-list Read this from start to finish and you will understand how to implement your own linked list, in a way that is appropriate for Python! (I linked to a specific section, but I would recommend to read the article from start to finish)

Comment: Your approach makes no sense. Get rid of *CTypes* and pointers (which btw have noting in common with *id*), learn and try implementing some linked list basics (with simple *Python* objects) and only then move to more complex stuff.